# List all entries in the current directory whose names contain only uppercase letters

Tags: command-line, bash, grep, ls

In one of my lab questions I was asked to list all entries(both files and folders) in the current directory whose names contain only uppercase letters using piping and grep command. Folders must have a forward slash displayed.
Initially, my solution looked like this:

```
ls -p | grep -e "^[[:upper:]]*\/?$"
```

I thought that I can protect the '/' sign with the backward slash(as in `echo \*` vs `echo *`). However, it doesn't work as intended.
One of my friends suggested the following solution:

```
ls -p | grep -e '^[[:upper:]]*/\?$'
```

I have no idea why the backward slash is used like this. What is even more weird,for me, that it actually produces the right result.
I was wondering if someone could explain where the mistake in my solution is and why the second version actually works.

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: It was explicitly said to use `grep` for that task , so that's what I went for. However, I would be grateful to see another way to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `grep` uses basic regular expressions (BRE), in which `?` matches a literal question mark. Adding the backslash made it have your desired interpretation as a quantifier meaning "zero or one occurrences of the previous expression" (i.e. optionally matching the trailing `/`).

From `man grep`:

> ```
> Basic vs Extended Regular Expressions
>            In  basic  regular expressions the meta-characters ?, +, {, |, (, and )
>            lose their special meaning; instead use the  backslashed  versions  \?,
>            \+, \{, \|, \(, and \).
> ```

You could achieve the same by switching to `grep` into extended regular expression (ERE) mode by adding the `-E` or `--extended-regexp` flag:

```
ls -p | grep -E -e '^[[:upper:]]*/?$'
```

Note that `/` is literal in both BRE and ERE - so doesn't need to be escaped in either case.

You could also consider using `-x` to enforce a whole-line match without the explicit `^` and `$` anchors.

---

Note that (although it's fine as an exercise), piping `ls` to `grep` is generally not a recommended way to select files. In bash, you could instead consider using extended globbing:

```
shopt -s extglob nullglob

ls -pd *([[:upper:]])
```

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot! I guess I did actually forgot about the Basic and Extended Regular Expressions. I will definitely look into that. Also, even though `/` is a literal , as you noted, you answer will be very helpful in the case when the character has to be protected.